# Detecting stop event of android media player

Tags: android, events, detect, android-mediaplayer

I want to detect the stop event of android music player. 

I am actually calling a method when the file stops playing.

There is an isPlaying method, but in order to get the stop event, I need to put it inside a while loop which might induce instability? 

Is there an elegant way to do this?

 This is the code I have:

```
mp.start(); // mp is the media player object
while (mp.isPlaying() == true) continue;
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MediaPlayer has an [OnCompletionListener callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) you can register to get notified when playback stops.